# Ace: Opening search/replace box programmatically

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm trying to integrate [Ace editor](http://ace.c9.io/) to my site. I know that it has keyboard shortcuts for opening the search and replace popups. Is there a way to open them programatically?

I noticed that `editor.searchBox` is `undefined` from the start but it is set when I hit cmd+F. I tried to look at ace/ext-searchbox.js but I can't find any method calls to try.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See implementation of find command in [default_commands.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/ca4148/lib/ace/commands/default_commands.js#L174).

```
config.loadModule("ace/ext/searchbox", function(m) {m.Search(editor)});
```

or you can use `editor.execCommand("find")`

Comment: Once the search box has been initialised and `editor.searchBox` is defined, you can easily toggle it with `editor.searchBox.show()` and `editor.searchBox.hide()`.